# How to resolve wireless soft blocking permanently

Tags: wireless, networking

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and my laptop has

```
Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan]
```

wireless. 
Every time I restart my laptop I am required to run following commands in order to resolve wireless soft blocking and make it connect to wireless networks:

```
sudo rfkill unblock wifi; sudo rfkill unblock all
ifconfig wlan0
```

How can I make this change permanent?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run scripts on start up?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

Comment: i am not asking about running scripts. i want to find some way to change some system files in order to solve this problem. why should i run an script every time i rum my system?

Comment: @MrAli a useful/half-baked definition of a *nix system file is "a script that runs every time the system is booted"

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Right above the line exit 0, add a single line:

```
rfkill unblock all
```

Proofread carefully, save and close gedit. You should be all set.